# It's time letting the [time-limiting] tag have its times gone here

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

There's no tag-wiki description and only 73 questions using the [time-limiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/time-limiting) tag ATM.

Also most questions I skimmed are (ab-)using it to ask about online code judge engine results, which are generally hard to answer, since their test cases are usually not disclosed, and the OPs rarely come up with a [Minimal, compilable, and verifyable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) making their problem reproducible.

---

Going through this [checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/186472) from Meta SE, these are my observations:

> 1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

It's not unambiguous. There are many reasons why code should and can be time limited.

> 2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site**

There's no concept for the tag, the tag-wiki is empty.

> 3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

It doesn't, there's neither a tag wiki carrying such information, nor the tag itself does carry any essential information

> 4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

It doesn't, as I mentioned for checklist point one.

I can't see any value for supporting that tag any longer at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Quote: "Almost all questions ... ask about".  That makes the tag unambiguous.  I'm sure it isn't difficult to get upvotes for this proposal, these are not popular questions.   But deleting the tag will not cause students to stop asking questions about it.  They'll merely be much harder to filter, I get to see *more* of them.  This is not a desirable outcome.

Comment: @Hans So you're thinking it could be useful as a kind of _VLQ honeypot_?

Comment: I'm thinking that your justification for deletion is quite invalid, by your own words. This tag is useful to me.  No different from how, say, the [php] tag is useful to me.  We don't normally describe that tag as a "honeypot".

Comment: @Hans Yeah, as mentioned if you're using that tag to detect questions about the common (unclear) TLE errors given as result of code running at Online code judge engines, it might help to detect those and close voting for missing MCVEs. Though I am not convinced that's the primary purpose of tags in Stack Overflow, but rather a useful side effect for close voters trying to work in a structured way.

Comment: In the context of the "I'm trying to beat a time limit" questions, it sounds like a meta tag.  It doesn't describe the content of the question, but the authors motivation to write it.  That the presence of meta tags makes bad questions easier to identify does not mean that we don't consider them noise.  I think the tag should be burninated.

Comment: I suggest getting rid of the tag and adding a time limiting feature to the bounty system.  Since bounties require reputation to add, this will limit and expose those questions that are legitimately time limited, but not allow those with limited reputation to over abuse the system and also provide a greater incentive for anyone wishing to get time sensitive questions answered to engage in the site.  You could then even keep the tag for those without the appropriate reputation to add a bounty, if you wanted.

Comment: @HansPassant You think we should keep an off-topic tag around because it makes it easier to find people who are posting off-topic questions?  That's got to be the most ridiculous tag justification I've ever heard.

Comment: @BJMyers Well, the concept of _honeypots_ isn't completely considerable as ridiculous or nonsense. But at least there should be a clear advise **not to use that tag** for certain reasons.

Comment: It is just as functional as [performance].  Which is not off-topic.  If this tag helps students find each other to solve their problems then all the power to them.

Comment: I think some commenters just want a easy way to ignore questions they aren't interested in answering or moderating. Yeah... that's not a good sign.